# Python print the result in separate array

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to print the rating result for different user in separate array. It can be solved by creating many arrays, but I didn't want to do so, because I have a lot of user in my Json file, so how can I do this programmatically?

python code

```
with open('/content/user_data.json') as f:
  rating = []
  js = json.load(f)
  for a in js['Rating']:
    for rate in a['rating']:
      rating.append(rate['rating'])

print(rating)
```

output

```
['4', '2', '5', '1', '3', '5', '2', '5']
```

my expected result

```
['4', '2', '5']
['1', '3']
['5', '2', '5']
```

json file

```
{
"Rating" : [
    {
      "user" : "john",
      "rating":[
        {
          "placename" : "Kingstreet Café",
          "rating" : "4"
        },
        {
          "placename" : "Royce Hotel",
          "rating" : "2"
        },
        {
          "placename" : "The Cabinet",
          "rating" : "5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "user" : "emily",
      "rating":[
        {
          "placename" : "abc",
          "rating" : "1"
        },
        {
          "placename" : "def",
          "rating" : "3"
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "user" : "jack",
      "rating":[
        {
          "placename" : "a",
          "rating" : "5"
        },
        {
          "placename" : "b",
          "rating" : "2"
        },
        {
          "placename" : "C",
          "rating" : "5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple one-liner

```
all_ratings = [list(map(lambda x: x['rating'], r['rating'])) for r in js['Rating']]
```

Explanation

```
all_ratings = [
    list(                                         # Converts map to list
        map(lambda x: x['rating'], r['rating'])   # Get attribute from list of dict
    ) for r in js['Rating']                       # Iterate ratings
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't only append all ratings to one list, but create a list for every user:

```py
with open('a.json') as f:
  ratings = [] #to store ratings of all user
  js = json.load(f)
  for a in js['Rating']:
    rating = [] #to store ratings of single user
    for rate in a['rating']:
      rating.append(rate['rating'])
    ratings.append(rating)
print(ratings)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just indent the print into the outer for loop and reset the array everytime.

```
for user in js["Rating"]:
    temp_array = []
    for rate in user["rating"]:
        temp_array.append(rate["rating"])
    print(temp_array)
```